# If I have multiple Identity Server 4 Instances - Do they each need their own Database?

Tags: load-balancing, identityserver4

Should I call one database ending in 1, and the next ending in 2, and so on?

Or can they spin up sharing one database?

I think since it is load balanced I would have to have 1 database, so the servers would act the same.  But when the identity server spins up to create it's db and it is already there - will that create an error?

These would be on separate server instances / load balanced

Comment: This will probably get close-votes as too-broad or opinion-based, but by definition, a correctly-configured load-balanced pair of web apps should share a single database, otherwise clients would have to know which server to hit for login, defeating the purpose of load-balancing... There's no reason to expect a second copy to blow up over an already-existing database any more than you'd expect a restart of the first-copy to crash. (If it does crash, You're Doing It Wrong.)

Comment: Ok thx!  I am copying the examples out of the MS book so It should be fine...

Comment: @user2704776 are you using one of the IdentityServer4 quick start examples?

Comment: We have modified the examples and have created an entire project with those as our base.  Our code tested fine in a dev / non replicated env.  But now we are moving to QA / replicated

Answer (score 1):

This is a opinion based answer (as i believe a lot of others will be too).

1. If your multiple instances of ID4 reflect different types of user base then you should have a separate db, essentially micro service formula.
2. If your multiple instances of ID4 are merely there to accommodate traffic load then and they refer to same user base then ideally you would want them pointing to single db instance.
   In addition if you have a heavy dependence on DB you could have multiple instances of db referenced by multiple ID4 instances, but would need to create a sync of some sort between the DB instances to ensure integrity and validity of data (you don't want user duplicated under different IDs between dbs).
   Each layer would have an load balancer of some sort.

Again all of this is dictated by your solution, non-functional requirements (performance,capacity etc.). So technically there is no right or wrong answer, but rather better and worse solution.